# Discrepancies between /etc/fstab options and mounted options in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, raspberry-pi

I have this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=9818D4D618D4B48A /mnt/Seriale ntfs3 defaults,noatime,nodiratime,nofail,async 0 0
```

And after mounting it and reading its options, I get:

```
rw,noatime,nodiratime,uid=0,gid=0,iocharset=utf8
```

Why don't the mounted options match? Why do the `nofail` and `async` options get removed, and why are the default options not listed?

Edit: Tested on an EXT4 partition with the same results.

Comment: `nofail` is used only at the time of the mount and checks if the device exists. It does not make sense to keep the option after the device is mounted. `async` is not supported on ntfs. It is also the default for ext4 so it does not need to be reported by `mount`. If you specified `sync` then the option would be listed.

Comment: So, the explanation would be that if a option is "default" it is not displayed ?

Comment: Correct. Otherwise you could see a long list of options displayed. Be aware that the default options are different depending on the file system used. For ext* some options are set in the superblock at the time the file system is created or as modified by `tune2fs`.

Comment: @roaima Done...

Comment: @doneal24 thank you +1 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comments into an answer...

The `nofail` option will never show up in the mount options as it is used only when you try to mount device. Basically, it does not report a failure if the device does not exist.

`async` is a different matter. It is not available for all filesystems, like NTFS, and I think it is silently ignored when it is not applicable. As for not being displayed after the system is mounted, `async` is one of the default options for ext* file systems. When using `mount` to display what options are enabled, any options that are default are not displayed.

If you think about it, some file systems have 10-20 options specific to that fs type. This is in addition to the 10+ options common to all file system types. If these weren't rolled into `default` and not displayed the output would be so long you would have a hard time picking out what you're actually looking for.